# too many css rules for the same selector zurb foundation-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I am working on a new project and I want to give Foundation Zurb a try. I like foundation zurb but what annoyed me the most is there are too many same css rules applied to the same selector as below:

[image]

As I saw there are more than 20s for the same selector.It does not happen for this selector only.

Debugging and Inspecting are really hard or almost impossible. I am not sure if this is the problem of foundation-rails gem or the foundation itself or did I miss something with foundation-rails integration ? are there any approached to clean this up ?

Really appreciate your help

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the gem?  This was apparently [a known issue](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/2803-include-exports-what-is-it-for) in Foundation.  Essentially rules were being defined in supporting sass files included repeately, e.g. `_global.scss`.  Haven't tried this myself, but according to the thread it was fixed in 5.5.

Comment: @numbers1311407 I used foundation-rails 5.4.5.0. After updating to the 5.5.1.1 it fixed. if you can post as an answer I can accept it. thank a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was known issue in recent versions of Foundation. Essentially rules were being defined in supporting sass files which were included repeately, e.g. `_global.scss`.  Every time the supporting file  was included, the rules would be redefined.

See more discussion in [this thread](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/19189-globals-are-repeated-multiple-times).

This problem should be resolved in Foundation 5.5.